# how to toggle sweetalert2 themes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert2

I have a sweetalert2 modal that has a toggle switch for dark mode, and I want to toggle darkmode for the modal. 
i tried:

```js
Swal.fire({
            title: 'Settings',
            icon: 'question',
            iconHtml: '<i class="fa fa-cog settings-modal-icon"></i>',
            html: settingsMenuHtml,
            showCloseButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Save',
            onOpen: () => {
                document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked = Nightly.isDark;
            },
      onBeforeOpen: () => {
        if(Nightly.isDark){
          var ss = document.createElement('link');
          ss.rel = "stylesheet";
          ss.href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-dark@4/dark.css";
          document.head.appendChild(ss);
        }  
      }
})
```

but this stops the entire page from loading. 
how do i fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [Sweetalert2 documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) for [willOpen](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#willOpen) and [didOpen](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#didOpen) which you should use instead of `onBeforeOpen` and `onOpen`.

Apart from that, I set `Nightly.isDark` to `true` (for dark mode) and I added some minimal code for `settingsMenuHtml`, which is necessary to make your modal work.

In addition, to enable toggling I created a `setCSSLink()` function which can be called when `willOpen` is fired and when the settings checkbox is clicked.

Here is a working code snippet:

```js
Nightly.isDark = true;

settingsMenuHtml = 
  '<input type="checkbox" onclick="Nightly.isDark = !Nightly.isDark; setCSSLink()">';

Swal.fire({
  title: 'Settings',
  icon: 'question',
  iconHtml: '<i class="fa fa-cog settings-modal-icon"></i>',
  html: settingsMenuHtml,
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Save',
  didOpen: () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked = Nightly.isDark;
  },
  willOpen: () => {
    setCSSLink()
  }
})

function setCSSLink() {
  var ss = document.createElement('link');
  ss.rel = "stylesheet";
  if (Nightly.isDark) {
    ss.href = "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-dark@4/dark.css";
  } else {
    ss.href = "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-minimal/minimal.css";
  }
  document.head.appendChild(ss);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fcmam5/nightly.js@v1.0/dist/nightly.min.js"></script>
```